# How to modify the path without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, html, history.js

After playing around with https://battlelog.battlefield.com/ and https://github.com/

I noticed it does not reload the page when changing the path. The incredible fit is that it does not use the hashtag unlike Facebook and Twitter.

So, how does it do it?

Comment: Here's a [relevant article](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2011/06/21/anatomy-of-an-html5-page-transition/).

Comment: Just a word of advice: make sure you don't break the back button. That is, if clicking a link starts a page transition and loads new content make sure I can "go back" to a previous state with the back button!

Comment: history.js handles that. the push state calls from a stack, so repeated back button presses will do exactly what you want it to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look into History.js and the push state options it supports. It's a very robust library.

Comment: I am looking at it thanks. I also noticed it is part of the [HTML5 History API](http://html5demos.com/history)

Comment: Also, just to be sure [this](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) is the lib you are talking about?

Comment: indeed it is the one I speak of.